# Поиск в контейнере (vector) по первой букве

Tags: c++

Как реализовать поиск по первой букве строки и вывод найденных строк?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

напишите в лоб

```
char c = '.';// нужный символ
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
  if (vec[i].length() < 1) continue;
  if (vec[i][0] == c) cout << "vec[i] << endl;
}
```

по желанию, цикл можно заменить на `for(auto s : vec)` и чуточку поправить тело.

Comment: Понял,спасибо,попробую сейчас.

Comment: Я бы собрал в один оператор - `if (vec[i].length() > 0 && vec[i][0] == c)`.

Comment: Этот пример рабочий.Пример zhihar не работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    v.push_back(std::string("abc"));
    v.push_back(std::string("dbc"));
    v.push_back(std::string("fbc"));
    v.push_back(std::string("fbcd"));

    struct find_func
    {
        char m_letter;

        find_func(const char letter) 
            :m_letter(letter) 
        { }

        bool operator()(const std::string &value) const 
        {
            return (value[0] == m_letter);
        }
    };

    do
    {
        res = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), find_func('f'));

        if (res != v.end())
        {
            // делаем что нам надо со строкой *res
            res ++;
        }

    } while (res != v.end();
```

Наверное есть варианты и короче - чтобы результат поиска сразу в массив записывался например

Comment: Ваш код может иногда падать.

Answer (score 1):

**вот попроще :)**

```
struct find_func
{
    char m_letter;
    find_func(const char letter) 
        :m_letter(letter) 
    { }

    bool operator()(const std::string &value) const 
    {
        return (value[0] == m_letter);
    }
};

std::vector<std::string> v;

v.push_back(std::string("abc"));
v.push_back(std::string("dbc"));
v.push_back(std::string("fbc"));
v.push_back(std::string("fbcd"));

std::vector<std::string> res(v.size());
std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), res.begin(), find_func('f'));
```

**А с лямбда еще проще**

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

v.push_back(std::string("abc"));
v.push_back(std::string("dbc"));
v.push_back(std::string("fbc"));
v.push_back(std::string("fbcd"));

std::vector<std::string> res(v.size());
std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), res.begin(), [](const std::string& value) {return (value[0] == 'f');});
```

Comment: И этот код может упасть.

Comment: @Zhihar, value[0] эта штука потенциально небезопасна, т.к. могут существовать пустые строки и обращение string[0] будет выбивать за границы контейнера. надо добавить что-то вроде `if string.length > 0`

Comment: Попробовал ,выдает пустую консоль.

Comment: @Kruk - так она ничего и не выводит, для вывода сделай:

`for (std::vector<std::string> it = res.begin(); it != res.end(); it++) std::cout << *it << std::endl;`

Comment: @goldstar_labs, проверил на пустой строке `std::string str; char c = str[0];` - выдает `0` и не падает, а вот `str.at(0)` как раз завалился, но согласен - на всякий случай проверку лучше добавить

Comment: Я же и написал, что иногда может падать. Обращение за пределы массива оно такое. Тут работает, а тут все закрашило. UB одним словом.